Some UTF-8 characters not being displayed properly in Windows
In some of my applications in windows, I'm don't see some of the UTF-8 icons being rendered properly.
An example is this url in chrome browser which should display a color-palette icon like this: , But I don't see a box being displayed (screenshot below)


I found below questions, but they are old and the solutions mentioned don't work.

Permanent fix for unicode characters not displaying correctly (as boxes)
Unicode characters suddenly start displaying as boxes in some applications


As you can see in that screenshot, this “font icon” is in the Private Use Area. This means that the Unicode standard (explicitly) does not actually say what character this is. Instead, every font could put a different glyph there. Regular fonts would not have a glyph for that at all, hence the placeholder.
So-called “icon fonts” make use of this. Instead of regular letters and numbers and whatnot, they have icon glyphs. So as not to conflict with regular fonts, nowadays they often don’t do stuff like changing the letter L to be a lock icon  but instead use code points that are reserved for non-conventional use—the Private Use Area.
If you want to use these icons outside a browser, you need to install the corresponding font. Note that unless whatever document you’re creating embeds either the font or an image of the text, others will need to install the font, too.
